# React-Native - useEffect causes infinite loop

Tags: react-native, loops, infinite

I am trying to show some dynamic content in my component but somehow useEffect causes a infinite loop.

What can be the problem?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    retrieveLocalData('following').then((contacts) => {
        setLocalData(JSON.parse(contacts));
    });
}, [getLocalData]);

async function retrieveLocalData(key) {
    try {
        return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
console.log('test'); // infinite
```

Code: https://codepen.io/eneskul/pen/OJWEgmw

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Answer

The infinite loop is a result of the `useEffect` hook updating the same value that is triggering the hook to run in the first place.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the problem:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({ foo: 'bar' });

useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve('{"foo":"bar"}').then((result) => {
        const newValue = JSON.parse(result);

        // `newValue` is a new object, even if its content is identical to `value`.
        setValue(newValue);
    });
}, [value]);
```

In this example, when `value` is set, it causes the `useEffect` hook to execute, which will asynchronously update `value` with a new object, which will cause the `useEffect` hook to execute again, and so on. Even though the contents of the objects are identical, the `JSON.parse` call creates a new object with a new reference.

You can prevent the infinite loop by doing a deep equality check of the two objects before updating the state. Using something like [Lodash's `isEqual` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) makes this pretty easy.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve('{"foo":"bar"}').then((result) => {
        setValue((prev) => {
            const newValue = JSON.parse(result);

            // Do a deep comparison and only update state with new object if content is different.
            return isEqual(prev, newValue) ? prev : newValue;
        });
    });
}, [value]);
```

In this example, the reference to `value` will only change if the contents of the objects are different.

However, this only explains what the problem is. I'm not sure what the right solution is for your problem, since it's not clear why the component only needs to load data from local storage into state when the state changes, but the state is only updated when it loads from local storage. There seems to be a ["chicken or the egg" problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) here. It feels like there should be something else that should trigger loading data from local storage into state, other than the data that was just loaded from local storage into state.

#### Previous Answer

The likely culprit here is `getLocalData` in the dependency list of the `useEffect` hook. If that is not a stable reference (i.e. the reference changes on each render), then it will cause the `useEffect` hook to execute, which will then trigger a state update, which will trigger a render, which will cause `useEffect` to execute again, which starts the whole thing over again.

In the sample code, it's not clear where `getLocalData` comes from. Wherever it comes from, you might consider wrapping it with the [`useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to create a stable reference. If it's just a typo and meant to be `retrieveLocalData`, then that is definitely the issue. Because `retrieveLocalData` is declared inside the component's render function, it will create a new instance of the function (with a new reference) on each render.

I would just move it inside the `useEffect` hook and eliminate the dependencies.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('following')
        .then((contacts) => {
            setLocalData(JSON.parse(contacts));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, getLocalData is a state. I only want to render if the getLocalData state been updated. So if getLocalData changes, useEffect should be called one more time.

Comment: Does `getLocalData` get updated when you call `setLocalData`?

Comment: OK. That's the cause of the infinite loop. The `useEffect` hook executes when `getLocalData` changes, then the hook asynchronously updates `getLocalData`, which causes the hook to execute again. I'm not sure I follow the reasoning for making `getLocalData` a dependency.

Comment: I mean i need to check with getLocalData if the state is being updated to call useEffect again, because if something changes, it should be listed in a List component. Any workaround suggestions for it?

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the same issue, I am getting auth_token from async storage and using (async function ) in useEffect hook, but getting infinit loop update. This is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137623/useasyncstorage-causes-infinit-loop-in-react-native