# UseAsyncstorage causes infinit loop in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Problem is that my component content rendering in an infinite loop.

```
const CustomDrawer =({navigation})=>{
    const [logged_in , setLoggedIn]= useState(false)

    useEffect(
        () => {
            useAsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token')
            .then((token) => {
                if(token){
                    setLoggedIn(true)
                }
            })
        } , []
    )

    const SignOut = ()=>{
        useAsyncStorage.removeItem('auth_token')
        .then(()=>{
            setLoggedIn(false)
        })
    }

    return(
        <View>
            <DrawerHeader username = 'Danish hello' /> // Custom drawer header
            <View style={styles.DrawerBody}>
                <CustomDrawerLink name="Home" iconName='home' navigationScreen='HomeScreen' navigation={navigation} />
                {
                    logged_in ?
                    <View>
                        <CustomDrawerLink name="Profile" iconName='user'  /> // Drawer custom buttons
                        <CustomDrawerLink name="Cart" iconName='hamburger'  />
                    </View>
                    : undefined
                }
                <Divider/>
                {
                    logged_in ?
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection:'row' , alignItems:'center'}} onPress={()=>{SignOut()}} >
                        <FontAwesome5 name='sign-out-alt' style={{fontSize:20, marginRight:10 , color:COLORS.red_color, width:35}} />
                        <Text style={{fontSize:16 , color:'gray'}}>Sign Out</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    :
                    <View>
                        <CustomDrawerLink name="Sign In" iconName='sign-in-alt'  navigationScreen='LoginScreen' navigation={navigation} />
                        <CustomDrawerLink name="Create New Account" iconName='user-plus'  navigationScreen='RegisterScreen' navigation={navigation} />
                    </View>
                }

            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

> Edited part
> ADDED PARENT COMPONENT Here it is

As you mentioned i am using useEffect Hook in my parent component, Here is the code

here i am making Drawer (Side navigation bar)

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()
```

Here is App component

```
const App = () =>{
  const network = useNetInfo()

  const [Scren_navigation , setNavigation] = useState('')
  const [activeDrawer , setActiveDrawer] = useState(<EmptyDrawer/>)

  const UpdateScreen = (props) =>{
    setNavigation(props.navigation)
    return activeDrawer
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
          network.isInternetReachable ?  setActiveDrawer(<CustomDrawer  navigation={Scren_navigation} />)  : setActiveDrawer(<NoInternetDrawer navigation={Scren_navigation} />)
      }, 5000);
  })


  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={({navigation}) => <UpdateScreen navigation={navigation} /> } >
        <Drawer.Screen name="StackNavigation"  component={Navigation} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I have added parent Component, Please let me know where i was doing wrong things

Comment: Does it keep occuring if you remove the `onPress={()=>{SignOut()}}`?

Comment: And you should return `null` to render nothing instead of `undefined`

Comment: Thanks you reply, but, Yes it still occurring when i remove onPress={()=>{SignOut()}} and change undefined to null.... any other solution

Comment: But when i remove useAsyncStorage it works fine, even i update state

Answer (score 1):

The package provides two API's one with `AsyncStorage` and the other one is `useAsyncStorage`. Both have different usage patterns, you have mixed both in your snippet. Checkout the code below for example usage of each API.

> AsyncStorage

```js
const CustomDrawer =({navigation})=>{
    const [logged_in , setLoggedIn]= useState(false)

    useEffect(
        () => {
            AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token')
            .then((token) => {
                if(token){
                    setLoggedIn(true)
                }
            })
        } , []
    )

    const SignOut = ()=>{
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth_token')
        .then(()=>{
            setLoggedIn(false)
        })
    }

    return ...;
}
```

> UseAsyncStorage

```js
const CustomDrawer =({navigation})=>{
    const [logged_in , setLoggedIn]= useState(false);
    const { getItem, setItem, removeItem } = useAsyncStorage('@storage_key');


    useEffect(
        () => {
           getItem('auth_token')
            .then((token) => {
                if(token){
                    setLoggedIn(true)
                }
            })
        } , []
    )

    const SignOut = ()=>{
       removeItem('auth_token')
        .then(()=>{
            setLoggedIn(false)
        })
    }

    return ...
}
```

The second problem is caused by the parent component because of a missing `[]` argument to the `useEffect`:

```
const App = () => {
    const network = useNetInfo()

    const [isRunningAvailabilityCheck, setIsRunningAvailabilityCheck] = useState(true);
    const [internetIsAvailable, setInternetIsAvailable] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setInternetIsAvailable(network.isInternetReachable);
            setIsRunningAvailabilityCheck(false);
        }, 5000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={({navigation}) => {
                if(isRunningAvailabilityCheck){
                    return <EmptyDrawer/>;
                }
                
                if(internetIsAvailable){
                    return <CustomDrawer  navigation={navigation} />
                }
                return <NoInternetDrawer navigation={navigation} />
            }}>
                <Drawer.Screen name="StackNavigation" component={Navigation}/>
            </Drawer.Navigator>

        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

[Async storage Docs](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api/#useasyncstorage)

Comment: I changed my code as you put in the answer. But still changing state in an infinite loop. in current second it shows logged_in component after a second it changes to logged_out component, and so on

Comment: Which version are you current using? AsyncStorage? Does the parent component also use useEffect?

Comment: I created a basic reproduction of the component and it seems to work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-resonance-moh9k, the problem is probably caused by a parent component.

Comment: Yes, it has a parent component with useEffect hook too. This is the version (    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",) and react native = "react-native": "0.64.0",

Comment: Is there is something wronge with parent useEffect hook?

Comment: When i remove useEffect from Parent Component, It works fine, How it happens? how did you find this may be an error? please let me know what was the problem in parent useEffect hook???? and thank you very much for your special time

Comment: Could you add the parent useEffect to your question?

Comment: I have added parent component code to my question, Please have a look

Comment: You seem to have missed the `[]` argument for useEffect in the parent component, check the updated answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help and special time, By adding argument it still not solve my problem. i just removed parent useEffect hook and it works fine

Comment: I updated the example, I think it is caused by rendering components in useState, would my approach work for your problem?

Comment: Hello, I was modified the code on my other way, and it works fine now, Thanks

Comment: How did you solve it? I am having this issue on a simple component and the dependencies has just the `getItem` and `setItem` functions, and it kept on entering the `useEffect` function. It should not be happening..? Edit: Seeing https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/635, it seems like `useAsyncStorage` is indeed the issue.